# Varying apply function on Columns when using Pandas TimeGrouper

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large time series dataset, I would like to do a count() on close_p but a sum() on prd_vlm.

```
                      open_p   high_p    low_p  close_p  tot_vlm  prd_vlm
datetime                                                                 
2005-09-06 16:33:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.25  1234.25      776       98
2005-09-06 16:34:00  1234.50  1234.75  1234.25  1234.50     1199      423
2005-09-06 16:35:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.50     1330      131
...
2017-06-25 18:41:00  2431.75  2432.00  2431.75  2432.00     5436      189
2017-06-25 18:42:00  2431.75  2432.25  2431.75  2432.25     5654      218
2017-06-25 18:43:00  2432.25  2432.75  2432.25  2432.75     5877      223
2017-06-25 18:44:00  2432.75  2432.75  2432.50  2432.75     5894       17
2017-06-25 18:45:00  2432.50  2432.50  2432.25  2432.25     6098      204
```

I can achieve this using the following code. But was wondering if there is a better way of achieve this using an apply function

```
group_count = df['close_p'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).count()
group_volume = df['prd_vlm'].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).sum()
grouped = pd.concat([group_count,group_volume], axis=1)
print(grouped)

            close_p    prd_vlm
datetime                      
2005-09-06      232     4776.0
2005-09-07     1039   631548.0
2005-09-08      999   544112.0
2005-09-09      810   595044.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use agg and apply different functions to different columns.

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).agg({'close_p':'count','prd_vlm':'sum'})
```

Comment: Neat! Can you create your own function for example "sum_even_days"

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just define your own functions and then call it like 'prd_vlm': sum_even_days .(no quotes around function name)